# What does Series: RR mean?

Tags: stocks, india

If you look at the stock of Embassy in NSE it has a "-RR" written after it (not there in BSE for some reason) and the NSE website shows it as being in Series: RR. I could not find any references to this particular series on Google. Can anyone please tell me what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So NSE has various series of different securities for trading on different trading segments listed on stock exchange. To ease up identifying the correct series & settlement segment of securities they have a table called legend of series. These series & legends are mostly useful to identify the most appropriate series, trade settlement market segment of any security.

RR here is just a legend for units of REIT that can be traded on Rolling Settlement segment

RT is also for units of REIT but these can be traded only on Trade To Trade (T2T) segment

https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/legend-of-series

https://www1.nseindia.com/emerge/trading/content/sme_mkt_segment.htm

Comment: The second link doesn't work. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Okay here's what I got from Zerodha Support.

> RR- Units of REITs. (real estate investment trust)
>
> A real estate investment trust (REIT) is a company that owns, and in
>   most cases operates, income-producing real estate. REITs own many
>   types of commercial real estate, ranging from office and apartment
>   buildings to warehouses, hospitals, shopping centers, hotels and
>   timberlands.

Apparently that's it, no fancy meaning like other "Series" on NSE. Or maybe even they don't know, either way, if someone does know something more, please do add-on.